# left join with 3 tables mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, join

I have 3 tables in my Database 
[image]

and i want to retrieve all products with their quantity from bill_Details tables.
This is the query:

```
SELECT p.prod_Id,p.prod_Name,COALESCE(sum(b.de_Quantity+b.de_Bonus),0)
,p.prod_Cost,p.prod_ExpDate,p.prod_BonusInfo,p.prod_Note 
FROM (products p
LEFT JOIN bill_Details b 
ON p.prod_Id=b.prod_Id) 
LEFT JOIN bills a 
ON b.bill_Id = a.bill_Id and a.cus_Sup=1 and a.archived=0  
GROUP BY p.prod_Id, p.prod_Name,p.prod_Cost,p.prod_ExpDate,p.prod_BonusInfo,
p.prod_Note 
ORDER BY p.prod_Name asc
```

The issue is that this query retrieve the same quantity when a.cus_Sup=1 or a.cus_Sup=0 !
Knowing that when a.cus_Sup=0 quantity should be 0 , and when a.cus_Sup=1 it's 29.5 for a specific product.

This is the data:
[image]

Comment: Try a where : select p.prod_Id,p.prod_Name,COALESCE(sum(b.de_Quantity+b.de_Bonus),0)
,p.prod_Cost,p.prod_ExpDate,p.prod_BonusInfo,p.prod_Note from (products p
left JOIN bill_Details b on p.prod_Id=b.prod_Id) left JOIN bills a on
b.bill_Id = a.bill_Id group by
p.prod_Id,p.prod_Name,p.prod_Cost,p.prod_ExpDate,p.prod_BonusInfo,
p.prod_Note order by p.prod_Name asc
where(a.cus_Sup=1 and a.archived=0)

Comment: @jdweng we can't place where clause after "group by". your query won't execute. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Below Query works for your case.

```
SELECT p.prod_id, 
       p.prod_name, 
       COALESCE(Sum(b.de_quantity + b.de_bonus), 0), 
       p.prod_cost, 
       p.prod_expdate, 
       p.prod_bonusinfo, 
       p.prod_note 
FROM   products p 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT bd.* 
                  FROM   bill_details bd 
                         JOIN bills a 
                           ON bd.bill_id = a.bill_id 
                  WHERE  a.cus_sup = 1 
                         AND a.archived = 0) b 
              ON p.prod_id = b.prod_id 
GROUP  BY p.prod_id, 
          p.prod_name, 
          p.prod_cost, 
          p.prod_expdate, 
          p.prod_bonusinfo, 
          p.prod_note 
ORDER  BY p.prod_name ASC
```

Comment: It will retrieve just products which has foreign records in bill_Details.

Comment: @BelalGhanem Edited query as per requirement.

Comment: @BelalGhanem I made changes as per your previous comment. Check it now if it works. I made changes to same post only..please notice edits made to this post.